# Pre-allocated vector of vectors yet still linear increase of memory while filling it

Tags: c++, qt, memory, vector

I am confused why the system monitor is showing me that my memory is increasing linearly, as I read in every line (into the same variable), while storing a split of the string in pre-allocated memory.

```
// pre-allocate
int rows = 100000;
int columns = 300;
QVector<QString> matrix_row;
matrix_row.resize(rows);
QVector< QVector<QString> > matrix;
matrix.resize(num_columns);
qFill(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), matrix_row);

int current_row = 0;
while(!filestream.atEnd())
{
        QString line = filestream.readLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < num_columns; i++)
        {
           matrix[i][current_row] = line.left(end[i]).right(grom[i]);
        }
        ++current_row;
}
```

Speed is a concern, so I am thinking perhaps something is wrong.

It starts at around 26% once the initial allocation, and it ends at around 65% of my 8gb of ram.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Even if you pre-allocate the vectors, you're still allocating more memory as you load the strings from the file into into the matrix.

Comment: @DavidBrown Why is that?

Comment: You can think of `QString` as being similar to a specialized `QVector<QChar>`. So, like `QVector`, it dynamically allocates the memory for the data it holds. Thus preallocating the `QVector<QString>` is only allocating space for `sizeof(QString)` which is just space for the pointer to the dynamic array and some other housekeeping variables.

Answer (score 2):

You must realize that your matrix has size 100 000 x 300, i.e. it holds 30 000 000 `QString` objects
~> right after the matrix is constructed, these strings are still empty ~> by the time you are filling the matrix, each new string additionally causes a small memory block (internally used by `QString`) to be allocated thus the memory requirements of your application continue to grow.

And since the `QVector` is a complex object that takes a bit more space than just the space required for its elements, this little mistake also matters: You `resize` the rows to have the length `rows` and you `resize` the matrix to have the amount of rows equal to `columns`. It should be the opposite way.

Also note that even after applying the aforementioned change, this code:

```
QVector<QString> matrix_row;
matrix_row.resize(columns);
QVector< QVector<QString> > matrix;
matrix.resize(rows);
qFill(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), matrix_row);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
QVector< QVector<QString> > matrix(rows, QVector<QString>(columns) );
```

Comment: The row and columns were arbitrarily chosen in this example. Would it be better if I would fill the matrix with a QString of the first element (and then after `filestream.seek(0)`)? Most likely the sizes of the variables won't change much, and the memory shouldn't expand that much?

Comment: I completely filled the matrix with the same string that I try to read in, but it still expands. Maybe it is more Mats Petersson's situation?

Answer (score 1):

In most modern operating systems if you allocate a fairly large chunk of memory, the OS just reserves the virtual space, but only once you write to the memory (or read from it) does the OS populate it with some physical memory.

Further, the string inside your vector is probably what takes up MOST of the space (unless the strings are indeed really tiny.

Comment: I think this might be it. Does this mean it is pointless to pre-allocate, or is there a better way to do it? Also, I do not understand the last paragraph?

Comment: Pre-allocating avoids "growing", which is probably a good thing. But it doesn't mean that all the memory is being used. The second paragraph tries to say that "You now have a vector or vector of string, but all strings are empty, and when you start putting stuff into the strings, the strings will take up more memory than empty strings".